# Duplicate key violation on UPDATE FROM SELECT query in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to `UPDATE` some column in dimension table `client` according to `event` table data:

```sql
UPDATE client AS c
SET 
    some_attr_last_value = last_attr_values.value 
FROM (

  SELECT
    l.client_id,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.client_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS num
  FROM event AS l
  WHERE 
    timestamp > DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month')

) AS last_attr_values

WHERE 
    last_attr_values.num = 1 AND 
    c.client_id = last_attr_values.client_id AND 
    c.some_attr_last_value <> last_attr_values.value;
```

I already have a few queries like above: they are update other columns in same manner (just with other columns) and works well. But one query produces the error:

> ERROR 6745:  Duplicate key values: 'client_id=…' -- violates constraint '… .client.C_PRIMARY'

But I don't try to change a `client_id`. Why this error occured?

I check the `client` table, but it have not duplicates. The `ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS('client')` also returns no violations.

Version is 7.2.2-1.

Comment: Is there any trigger on that table? I'm not familiar with vertica, so I'm just throwing this out there.

Comment: As I know Vertica does not support triggers.

Comment: Can you add CREATE TABLE of `event` and `client`, and the exact UPDATE statement - and, if that applies, the bunch of previous UPDATE statements that you fired in the same transaction (assuming you have autocommit turned off or fired a BEGIN TRANSACTION before)?

Comment: There are about 200 columns in the `event` table and about 50 columns in the `client`, so I'm afraid this is too much to post in question. 
About the transactions: I tried to execute this query in different ways without any previous queries (and from different sessions and DB-users) and always got same error.

Comment: @Timurib Please post the client.C_PRIMARY constraint?

Comment: @woot Are you mean `v_catalog` parameters about this constraint? Is a _table_name: client, column_name: client_id, constraint_name: C_PRIMARY, constraint_type: p, is_enabled: true_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with your client table it is with your inner select.

```
SELECT
    l.client_id,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.client_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS num
  FROM event AS l
  WHERE 
    timestamp > DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month')
```

What is it in the SELECT that ensures that you have one record per client?

Let's suppose that you have events where you have multiple events for multiple clients.

- Client_id 1 10:00
- Client_id 1 10:05
- Client_id 9 10:05
- Client_id 9 10:06
- Client_id 1 10:07

Because your window function is ordered by timestamp

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.client_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS num
```

You will get

- Client_id 1 1
- Client_id 1 2
- Client_id 9 1
- Client_id 9 2
- Client_id 1 1 <---- 2nd Client_id 1 with a Row_number of 1!

I believe that you need to include Client_id in your ORDER BY for your query to work.

---

**Update**: After some time the error happened again. I tried to use the above solution, but unfortunately it did not help. The error was overcome only using a temporary table:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE last_values ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS 
AS SELECT client_id, value FROM (
  SELECT
    l.client_id,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.client_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS num
  FROM event AS l WHERE timestamp > DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month')
) last_values WHERE last_values.num = 1;

UPDATE client AS c 
SET some_attr_last_value = last_values.value
FROM last_values 
WHERE c.client_id = last_values.client_id AND c.some_attr_last_value <> last_attr_values.value

DROP TABLE last_values;
```

So although the problem resolved, I did not find out its exact cause.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce your example: https://pastebin.com/raw/a3kctbei - all `client_id` are divided by own frames and sequentually ordered, no duplicates of pairs. Perhaps I'm missing something?
Unfortunately I cannot just replace a sort from timestamp to client_id, because I need to exactly last values.

Comment: Try order by both client_id and timestamp.  Not one instead of the other.  I have run into this problem when there were no duplicates in neither data set, the issue was that the query optimisation engine had no way of knowing that the key was unique and therefore complained about it.

Comment: I'm confused, but some hours ago the error _just gone without any changes of the query_. We successfully done the update by all rows for all time (without condition for last month) and no duplicates were found.
I'm finally understood your solution, but now I just cannot check it. Anyway, I'm grateful for you for the information and think it may be helpful for others, so I think the answer should be marked as accepted. Thank!

Comment: After some time the error happened again. I tried to use the above solution, but unfortunately it did not help. The error was overcome only using a temporary table. I further described this in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Vertica checks constraints at `SELECT` time normally, not when you UPDATE.  Check your table for dups.

I think the latest release of Vertica does have some options now for checking at `INSERT` and `UPDATE` but that isn't the default.

Comment: Yes, I already check the table and it does not contain duplicates (each `client_id` is contained in `client` only once).